# How to slice a Tensor by another Tensor in Keras?

Tags: keras, slice, tensor

I have a Keras network with two inputs:

- image of shape (128, 128, 3)
- bounding-box of shape (4), i.e. (x0, y0, x1, y1)

In my network definition, I need to include the extraction of the image patch defined by the bounding-box from the input image, but I do not know how (or my attempts did not work). Here is my current attempt to achieve this, can someone please help me to understand slicing Tensors by Values of other Tensors in Keras?

```
# get masked image and bounding box information as inputs
masked_img = Input(shape=self.input_shape)
mask_bounding_box = Input(shape=(4,))

# fill in the masked region and extract the fill-in region
filled_img = self.generator(masked_img)
fill_in = K.slice(filled_img, (int(mask_bounding_box[0]), int(mask_bounding_box[1])),
                              (int(mask_bounding_box[2]), int(mask_bounding_box[3])))
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Any hint in the right direction would help me, please ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

here's a native numpy solution.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(48).reshape(3,4,4)
a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27],
        [28, 29, 30, 31]],

       [[32, 33, 34, 35],
        [36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43],
        [44, 45, 46, 47]]])

box = (1,1,2,2) # slicing from (1,1) to (2,2) 
b = a[:, box[0]:box[2]+1, box[1]:box[3]+1] # slicing on all channels
b
array([[[ 5,  6],
        [ 9, 10]],

       [[21, 22],
        [25, 26]],

       [[37, 38],
        [41, 42]]])
```

Keras.backend.slice() requires starts and offsets, so you could do it like this:

```
import keras.backend as K
start=(0,1,1) # 1st channel, x1, y1
sizes=(3,2,2) # number of channels, x2-x1+1, y2-y1+1
with sess.as_default():
     b=K.slice(a, start, sizes)
     print(b.eval())

[[[ 5  6]
  [ 9 10]]

 [[21 22]
  [25 26]]

 [[37 38]
  [41 42]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the start and sizes tuples from the bounding box input tensor. I have a tensor of shape (4), i.e. (x1, x2, y1, y2)?

Comment: start: (0, x1, y1)
sizes: (# of channels in input image, x2-x1+1, y2-y1+1). Added it to the answer above.

Comment: I did try it all day long, but could not achieve what I want. Slicing as you showd me works, but only outside of the keras network definition. When I try to use additional inputs for passing the bounding box information, it does not work. I tried a lot already.

    `fill_in = Lambda(lambda args: K.slice(args[0], (0, args[1][0], args[1][1], 0), (len(args[0]), 
    box_height, box_width, 3)))([filled_img, mask_pos])`

Comment: Why is it so hard in keras to just crop a tensor to a bounding box that is specified dynamically by the network inputs?

Comment: What I need is a Keras-Compatible Function like:
    `extract_bounding_box_region(image, box_x, box_y, box_width, box_height)`,
where all parameters are given by Input tensors

Comment: Thats more or less the template I need to fill in a way that actually works:

    `fill_in = Lambda(lambda img: K.slice(img, (0, BOX_X, BOX_Y, 0),(BATCH_SIZE, 32, 32, 3)))(filled_img)`

Comment: Did you get the solution to this problem? I also require the values from one tensor to slice a specific channel from another tensor. The indices from the former tensor will vary with each input, just like your bounding box coordinates.